# Change state in global function with ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, state

I am trying to change the state of my ionic app in a global function in my App.js.

This is the function:

> function handleOpenURL(url) {...};

I`m using the Custom URL Scheme plugin for Cordova.

I want it to change the state of the app depending on the url from

> function handleOpenURL(url) {...};

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it:

Create Controller:

```
.controller('URLController', function($scope, URLService){
    $scope.loadViaURL= function(url){
        URLService.openUrltemplate(url);
    } })
```

And add it to your body in the index.html:

```
<body ng-controller='URLController'>
```

The controller uses the function: openUrltemplate from URL Service:

```
.factory('URLService', function($state){
    function openUrltemplate(url){   
           $state.go(YOURCODE);     
    }
    return({
         openUrltemplate:  openUrltemplate
    });   
})
```

Finally in the global handleOpenUrl()-function:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var appLaunchedController = angular.element(body).scope();
    appLaunchedController.loadViaURL(url);
```

HaVe FuN :D